# How to update dataframe columns based on the similarity of in certain values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cross-reference

I have user dataframe with messy city (some are missing as well) names looks as following:

```
a = [['New York', '10460', '21', '321321.12' ], 
['Brooklyn', '11219', '03', '2432567.52'], [' ', '11363', '320', '34325.543]]
userdf = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['City', 'Post Code', 'Lat', 'Long])
userdf
```

Now I want to fix the names in the City, Lat, and Long columns based on the Postcode by looking at the corresponding Postcode in the location Dataframe with official details as following:

```
location = [['Bronx', '10460', '21', '321321.12' ], 
['Brooklyn', '11219', '03', '2432567.52'], [' ', '11363', '320', '34325.543]]
locationdf = pd.DataFrame(location, columns=['City', 'Post Code', 'Lat', 'Long])
```

I have tried multiple ways and they all failed in every way. How I can update some columns in `userdf` using values from `locationdf` based on the condition `userdf['Post Code']` equals `locationdf['Post Code']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .loc. For example if you wanted to change the city.

```
userdf['City'] = locationdf.loc[userdf['Post Code']==locationdf['Post Code']]['City']
```

Comment: This works well when the data type is similar. I find it useful. Thank you.